# Zend framework 2: Form bind not setting the values extracted from database

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to create a form with Zend Framework 2 for my application and I have everything in place and the form is getting displayed but my issue is I am not able to bind the initial form values that come from the database

```
$myUserDetails = <details of my user coming from DB>;
$form = $form->bind($myUserDetails); //This should set the values for the form to display but it doesnt
```

My display logic is simple as shown below

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', 
$this->url('<routename>',array('action'=>'<actionname>')));
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form) . PHP_EOL;
echo $this->formRow($form->get('email_id')) . PHP_EOL;
echo $this->formRow($form->get('dob')) . PHP_EOL;
echo $this->formRow($form->get('gender')) . PHP_EOL;
echo $this->formRow($form->get('user_page_name')) . PHP_EOL;
echo $this->formInput($form->get('submit')) . PHP_EOL;
echo $this->form()->closeTag($form) . PHP_EOL;
```

Now I tried to set the data from my object that I bind to the form in my controller action

```
$myUserDetails = <details of my user coming from DB>;
$form = $form->bind($myUserDetails);
$data = $myUserDetails->getArrayCopy();
$form->setData($data['data']);
```

This seems to work somehow and is displaying my values in the view. So i just want to know what have I done wrong in my first approach? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you give us more information about the `$myUserDetails` object. Is it an object and if yes what interfaces implements?

Comment: It is an object of my custom model with just the column name getter setters and exchangeArray and getArrayCopy function. Is it required to implement the interface to just bind the values? As I think getArrayCopy is the function which just converts the Object to an array which can be binded to the data of the form. Currently I havent implemented any interfaces. Thanks

Comment: Having the `getArrayCopy()` is enough I think. I see that `$myUserDetails->getArrayCopy();` returns an array and you pass the `data` key to the `$form->setData($data['data']);`. This could be the problem. Try prepare your `getArrayCopy()` to return only the parameters of the db fields/form fields.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Stoyan Dimov I solved the issue. Basically it was with getArrayCopy function in my model as I was direcly returning an array which was enclosed in an index 'data'

So I changed my getArrayCopy to

```
public function getArrayCopy() {
        $data = get_object_vars($this);
        return $data['data'];
    }
```

And voila it worked.

Thanks again Stoyan Dimov